# How to set linear constraints on elements of a long list

Tags: mathematical-optimization, programming

I would like to minimize over quite large set of $a_i$ some function $f(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n)$ subject to a set of $k$ linear constraints:
$$
i=1\dots n: \quad a_i\ge0;\quad j=1\dots k:\quad\sum_{i=1}^n m_{ji}a_i\ge b_j,\tag1
$$
where the matrix $m$ and the vector $b$ are given. This is very similar to `LinearProgramming`, except for the art of the minimized function. Ideally the command should have 3 parameters: $f,m,b$ and probably the size of the vector $n$, though the latter can be read from the dimensions of the matrix $m$ and should return the minimized value of $f$ and the corresponding minimizing vector.

I can find the solutions for small $m$ with `Minimize`, but it is not realistic to type all the constraints by hand.

For test purpose the function $f$ can be considered just quadratic $f=a.M.a$.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: tried [QuadraticOptimization](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/QuadraticOptimization.html)?. e.g. `QuadraticOptimization[{m,ConstantArray[0,n]},{m,b}]`

Comment: @kglr My function is in fact not quadratic. I would like to have a general solution for an arbitrary (scalar) function $f$.

Comment: Please check this https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/795  J. C. Culioli made excellent work more than 20 year ago.

Comment: @PierreALBARÈDE Thank you. I will check. But as I already said `Minimize` works well with my function. The only problem is that I don't know a way to submit my linear constraints in a "compressed form".

Comment: So it only a problem of syntax?

Comment: @PierreALBARÈDE I assume yes.

Comment: how about `Element[m.a-b, NonNegativeReals]` as the constraint?

Comment: That will be something like `Minimize[{f @@ Table[_, {i, n}], 
  Sequence @@ Table[Sum[_, {i, n}]>0, {j, n}]}, Table[_, {i, n}]]`.

Comment: @PierreALBARÈDE I would be thankful if you give an answer with an working example. Then I will try to understand how it works.

Comment: @kglr I will try!

Comment: .. or `VectorGreaterEqual[{m.a,b}]`?

Comment: @kglr `VectorGreaterEqual`... Never heard about this. You are a magician!

Comment: @kglr One more question. I also would like to avoid typing `{a1,a2,\dots,an}` for the dummy vector in question. How to avoid this?

Comment: drer, try  `avec = Array[a, n]`?

Comment: @kglr I tried but it did not work. I will check once more.

Comment: you need to assign a value to  `n` first; or define `ClearAll[avec];avec[n_Integer]:=Array[a,n]` and use it as `avec[5]`, `avec[100]`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify linear inequality constraints succinctly using [`VectorGreaterEqual`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VectorGreaterEqual.html) or using [`Element`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Element.html) + [`NonNegativeReals`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonNegativeReals.html):

```
constraints1 = Element[{m.a - b, a}, NonNegativeReals];

constraints2 = VectorGreaterEqual /@ {{m.a, b}, {a, 0}};
```

***Example:***

```
SeedRandom[1];
ClearAll[a, b, m]

n = k = 4;
m = RandomReal[4, {n, k}];
a = Array[Symbol["a" <> ToString[#]] &, n]
b = RandomReal[{-3, 3}, k];

obj = a.m.a;

sol1 = Minimize[{obj, constraints1}, a]
```

> ```
> {0.553132, {a1 -> 0., a2 -> 0., a3 -> 0.807969, a4 -> 0.}}
> ```

We get the same result using `constraints2`:

```
sol2 = Minimize[{obj, constraints2}, a]
```

> ```
> {0.553132, {a1 -> 0., a2 -> 0., a3 -> 0.807969, a4 -> 0.}}
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much! It is always a pleasure to learn from experts.